# How can I implement Tree structure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, tree

I want to implement generic cv creator web application. How to keep this information in mysql database?

For example;
Adding in education imformation part;
Someone want to add only school name unlike someone want to add extra information.

- Oxford University

or
(I dont know tree's depth.)

- Oxford University

  - Object Oriented Programming(cse241)

    - ...
    - ...
  - Database(cse314)

Comment: You can add a column to your target table in which each value of that column refers to its corresponding parent row (the value of the primary key). Each node in the tree can then contain random number of sub-nodes.  The tree in this way can expand infinitely up to the level of your choice but implementing this kind of stuff is usually not recommended as it is impractical especially when the tree size is exponentially increased. Levels of the tree we want to implement should be  minimized as many as possible as it is always possible to classify every business in the world in a few categories.

Comment: What has this to do with JSF? This question should be totally db oriented. Nor java, jsf or javaee are mentioned in the content.

Comment: You are right, sorry. @xtreme-biker